# How to set the JAN month to 01 in angular material 2 Datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I just realised that the datepicker calendar starts at the month of 00,
how can I set it to 01 in the datepicker component ?

[image]

**datepicker.component.ts**

```
...

  export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('f') searchForm: NgForm 
  appBase: string;
  errorMessage: string;
  initialDateFrom = new Date();

...
```

**datepicker.component.html**

```
<span class="calendar-to">
        <button md-raised-button (click)="pickupTo.open()" class="search--icon"></button>
        <input  [mdDatepicker]="pickupTo"
                placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                name="date_to"
                ngModel>
        <md-datepicker touchUi="true" #pickupTo></md-datepicker>
    </span>
```

Comment: This is how dates natively work, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: what is the version of your angular material?

Comment: @Vadamadafaka 2.0.0-beta.10